# textarea auto height if value is set programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, height

firstly I was expecting textarea css `height:auto` to make it really `height:auto` i.e. matched to content
shortly - it doesn't work

here is my `js` way to make it `height:auto`
problem - it only works if I type inside the textarea and not if I set the value by clicking on a button

```js
$('.btx').on('input', function(){
    $(this).css('height', 'auto').height(this.scrollHeight + 'px');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.btx').val("lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit\namet");
  $('.btx').css('height', 'auto').height(this.scrollHeight + 'px');
});
```

```css
.btx{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    resize:none;
    padding:9px 20px;
    line-height:25px;
    font-family:courier;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<textarea class='btx'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @Rory McCrossan's answer, as you already define an input event, I suggest triggering the input after you click the button.

```js
$('.btx').on('input', function(){
    $(this).css('height', 'auto').height(this.scrollHeight + 'px');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.btx').val("lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit\namet");
  $('.btx').trigger('input');
});
```

```css
.btx{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    resize:none;
    padding:9px 20px;
    line-height:25px;
    font-family:courier;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<textarea class='btx'></textarea>
```

Comment: @qadenz, I accidentally found a downside of this solution. ```Jquery trigger event doesn't work on hidden elements in mac safari.```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because in the `button` event handler `this` will be the `button`, not the `.btx` element, so you're reading the `scrollHeight` from the wrong place.

I'd suggest caching a reference to `.btx` in a variable which you can then refer back to in order to set/get the properties you need. Try this:

```js
let $btx = $('.btx').on('input', function() {
  $btx
    .css('height', 'auto')
    .height(this.scrollHeight + 'px');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $btx
    .css('height', 'auto')
    .val("lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit\namet")
    .height($btx.get(0).scrollHeight + 'px');
});
```

```css
.btx {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: courier;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<textarea class='btx'></textarea>
```

Comment: do you see any downside of `ikhvjs`'s solution, pls